# How to build a Markov's chain transition probability matrix

Tags: r, markov-chains

I am learning R on my own and I am having some troubles trying to build a transition probability matrix in Rstudio using the markovchain package. First I tried to calculate the transition probabilities of a DNA sequence.

```
ATTCAACACATCCAGCCACATGCTCCGAGAGGAGGCAGAGGGCCCCCGGAATGATGCTTACCGAGATTCTTGTTTTTATCCTCGTGGTTGTTTAAAAACGAGTTGAAACTGACGGCATGTCGGACTATAAGCTACTTACTCACCATAGACGTGACCATAGGCCCTAAAACGTTACCGAGATATTCACTTCTAATAACAGTTGTCGGCAGAGCCAAAAGGCCGGGTGATAATACTTTAAAAAGGGAGTTGATTGTTGTATCTAATCCTAGAATGTCAAGAGCGACCATAACAAGATAATTCGGCAGAGCCAGAAAGCGTTCAAGGACTAGAACCATACCGAGACGCAAACGTTCAGGTCGAACTCTAATACCGATTAGT
```

But how can the transition probability matrix be calculated in a sequence like this, I was thinking of using R indexes but I don't really know how to calculate those transition probabilities.

Is there a way of doing this in R? 
I am guessing that the output of those probabilities in a matrix should be something like this:

```
     A    T    C    G
  A 0.60 0.10 0.10 0.20
  T 0.10 0.50 0.30 0.10
  C 0.05 0.20 0.70 0.05
  G 0.40 0.05 0.05 0.50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `markovchain` package for help with this. First, your data

```
seq <- "ATTCAACACATCCAGCCACATGCTCCGAGAGGAGGCAGAGGGCCCCCGGAATGATGCTTACCGAGATTCTTGTTTTTATCCTCGTGGTTGTTTAAAAACGAGTTGAAACTGACGGCATGTCGGACTATAAGCTACTTACTCACCATAGACGTGACCATAGGCCCTAAAACGTTACCGAGATATTCACTTCTAATAACAGTTGTCGGCAGAGCCAAAAGGCCGGGTGATAATACTTTAAAAAGGGAGTTGATTGTTGTATCTAATCCTAGAATGTCAAGAGCGACCATAACAAGATAATTCGGCAGAGCCAGAAAGCGTTCAAGGACTAGAACCATACCGAGACGCAAACGTTCAGGTCGAACTCTAATACCGATTAGT"
```

Then use the package

```
library(markovchain)
base_sequence <- strsplit(seq, "")[[1]]
mcX <- markovchainFit(base_sequence)$estimate
mcX

#           A         C         G         T
# A 0.3000000 0.2250000 0.2583333 0.2166667
# C 0.2857143 0.2619048 0.2380952 0.2142857
# G 0.3764706 0.1882353 0.2117647 0.2235294
# T 0.3068182 0.2159091 0.1818182 0.2954545
```

Answer (score 1):

Create DNA

```
DNA <- "ATTCAACACATCCAGCCACATGCTCCGAGAGGAGGCAGAGGGCCCCCGGAATGATGCTTACCGAGATTCTTGTTTTTATCCTCGTGGTTGTTTAAAAACGAGTTGAAACTGACGGCATGTCGGACTATAAGCTACTTACTCACCATAGACGTGACCATAGGCCCTAAAACGTTACCGAGATATTCACTTCTAATAACAGTTGTCGGCAGAGCCAAAAGGCCGGGTGATAATACTTTAAAAAGGGAGTTGATTGTTGTATCTAATCCTAGAATGTCAAGAGCGACCATAACAAGATAATTCGGCAGAGCCAGAAAGCGTTCAAGGACTAGAACCATACCGAGACGCAAACGTTCAGGTCGAACTCTAATACCGATTAGT"
```

Split it character by character

```
DNA_list <- unlist(strsplit(DNA, split = ""))
```

Retrieve unique elements

```
DNA_unique <- unique(DNA_list)
```

Create an empty matrix

```
matrix <- matrix(0, ncol = length(DNA_unique), nrow=length(DNA_unique))
```

Fill it: to elt i and element i + 1 and add one in the corresponding cell of the matrix.

```
for (i in 1:(length(DNA_list) - 1)){
  index_of_i <- DNA_unique == DNA_list[i]
  index_of_i_plus_1 <- DNA_unique == DNA_list[i + 1]
  matrix[index_of_i, index_of_i_plus_1] = matrix[index_of_i, index_of_i_plus_1] + 1
}
```

Normalize it

```
matrix <- matrix / rowSums(matrix)

> matrix
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.3000000 0.2166667 0.2250000 0.2583333
[2,] 0.3068182 0.2954545 0.2159091 0.1818182
[3,] 0.2857143 0.2142857 0.2619048 0.2380952
[4,] 0.3764706 0.2235294 0.1882353 0.2117647
```

NB: There might be a way to perform it in a faster way if you have really large DNA to compute. But here it seeems to be fast enough.